# How to create an on/off switch with Javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a sliding switch. On the left would be Off and on the right would be On. When the user toggles the switch, I want the 'slider' portion to slide to the other side and indicate it is off. I could then have a callback that takes as input the state of the toggle switch so I can act accordingly.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: [Not sure from your question, but probably you are looking for something like this.](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html)

Comment: Not sure how this question is too broad after nearly 5 years of being open. It clearly outlines what I am looking for and got a response the same day that perfectly answers the question. The question still gets lots of activity and new responses that are current are posted 4.5 years after asking the question.

Comment: I wrote [a tutorial](http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs) about how to create on/off switches with CSS only (also checkboxes and radios). [Here you can see the demo](http://custom-inputs.felixhagspiel.de/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You mean something like IPhone checkboxes? 
Try [Thomas Reynolds' iOS Checkboxes script:](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html)

> Once the files are available to your site, activating the script is very easy:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $(':checkbox').iphoneStyle();
> });
> ```

Results:

[image]

Comment: beautiful. I don't own an iphone so i didn't know what this was called.

Comment: http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/ - service for Generate pure CSS3 On/Off flipswitches with animated transitions.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's **not** free for commercial use.

Answer (score 45):

check out this generator: [On/Off FlipSwitch](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/)

you can get various different style outcomes and its css only - no javascript!

Answer (score 18):

**Using plain javascript**

```
<html>

  <head>

     <!-- define on/off styles -->
     <style type="text/css">
      .on  { background:blue; }
      .off { background:red; }
     </style>

     <!-- define the toggle function -->
     <script language="javascript">
        function toggleState(item){
           if(item.className == "on") {
              item.className="off";
           } else {
              item.className="on";
           }
        }
     </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <!-- call 'toggleState' whenever clicked -->
     <input type="button" id="btn" value="button" 
        class="off" onclick="toggleState(this)" />
  </body>

</html>
```

**Using jQuery**

If you use jQuery, you can do it using the [toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) function, or using the [toggleClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass) function inside click event handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#myButton').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("btnClicked");
    });
});
```

Using jQuery UI effects, you can animate transitions: http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this using HTML and CSS and convert a checkbox into a HTML Switch.

```css
    input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
      padding: 2px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #dddddd;
      -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
      -moz-border-radius: 30px;
      -ms-border-radius: 30px;
      -o-border-radius: 30px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
    input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 1px;
      left: 1px;
      bottom: 1px;
      content: "";
    }
    input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
      right: 1px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
      -moz-border-radius: 30px;
      -ms-border-radius: 30px;
      -o-border-radius: 30px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
      -o-transition: background 0.4s;
      transition: background 0.4s;
    }
    input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
      width: 40px;
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
      -moz-border-radius: 100%;
      -ms-border-radius: 100%;
      -o-border-radius: 100%;
      border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
      -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
      transition: margin 0.4s;
    }
    input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
      background-color: #8ce196;
    }
    input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
      margin-left: 60px;
    }
    
    .cmn-toggle {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -9999px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .cmn-toggle + label {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
          <div class="switch">
            <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round"  type="checkbox">
            <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
          </div>
```

Comment: Everytime i have to make a switch, i use this method. Just a simple checkbox with a label and CSS.

Answer (score 8):

## Initial answer from 2013

If you don't mind something related to Bootstrap, an excellent (unofficial) [Bootstrap Switch is available](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch).

[image: Classic 2013 Switch]

It uses radio types *or* checkboxes as switches. A `type` attribute has been added since V.1.8.

Source code is [available on Github](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch).

## Note from 2018

I would not recommend to use those kind of old Switch buttons now, as they always seemed to [suffer of usability issues](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan) as pointed by many people.

Please consider having a look at [modern Switches like those](https://react-component.github.io/switch/examples/simple.html).

[image: Modern 2018 Switch]

Comment: The link redirects to http://bootstrap-switch.org/ which fails to load. Use http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ (with www; thanks to SO for visually hiding www in my link) instead which does load.

Comment: www.bootstrap-switch.org actually redirects to a scam website: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bNsT.png

Comment: @BentheCoder thanks for reporting. Made the link fallback to GitHub as no website exist for this module anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Outline: Create two elements: a slider/switch and a trough as a parent of the slider. To toggle the state, switch the slider element between an "on" and an "off" class. In the style for one class, set "left" to 0 and leave "right" the default; for the other class, do the opposite:

```
<style type="text/css">
.toggleSwitch {
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
    /* add other styling as appropriate to position element */
    position: relative;
}
.slider {
    background-image: url(...);
    position: absolute;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
}
.slider.on {
    right: 0;
}
.slider.off {
    left: 0;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceClass(elt, oldClass, newClass) {
    var oldRE = RegExp('\\b'+oldClass+'\\b');
    elt.className = elt.className.replace(oldRE, newClass);
}
function toggle(elt, on, off) {
    var onRE = RegExp('\\b'+on+'\\b');
    if (onRE.test(elt.className)) {
        elt.className = elt.className.replace(onRE, off);
    } else {
        replaceClass(elt, off, on);
    }
}
</script>
...
<div class="toggleSwitch" onclick="toggle(this.firstChild, 'on', 'off');"><div class="slider off" /></div>
```

Alternatively, just set the background image for the "on" and "off" states, which is a much easier approach than mucking about with positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Shield UI's [Switch widget](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/switch/preferences). It is as easy to use as this:

```
<input id="switch3" type="checkbox" value="" />

<script>
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#switch3").shieldSwitch({
        onText: "Yes, save it",
        ffText: "No, delete it",
        cls: "large"
    });
  });
</script>
```