# mobile html form - how to create a checkbox?

Tags: forms, html, mobile

How do I create a html checkbox that looks like the mobile ON/OFF checkbox?

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried searching this on net? I don't think so.

Comment: Honest to god I did. I also keep looking as I'm waiting for answers...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an on/off switch with Javascript/CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957466/how-to-create-an-on-off-switch-with-javascript-css)

Comment: Try this: http://www.tobypitman.com/iphone-style-checkboxes-with-css3/ and  http://devgrow.com/iphone-style-switches/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution: http://www.tobypitman.com/iphone-style-checkboxes-with-css3/