# Disable on/off icon for boolean field in Django

Tags: django, user-interface, django-admin, boolean

Sometimes it is not desirable to show 'on/off' icon for a boolean field.

Example:

- `error` field shows a happy green 'ok' icon when there's an error *or*
- `blocked=True` displayed as a green 'ok' while `blocked=False` as a 'no entry' sign.

In such cases it'd be better to keep the original `True`/`False` behaviour.

Is there a more elegant way than creating a special method returning for example `self.error` and adding `short_description`, `ordering`, etc. to it?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. Could you please elaborate with some real example.

Comment: Imagine a `User` model, which has a field `is_blocked`. Default admin widget shows _green_ icon when the user is blocked and _red_ icon when the user is not blocked. Which is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no dirtiness in using this code `admin.py`:

```
from mysite.models import Test
from django.contrib import admin

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_blocked_col',)

    def is_blocked_col(self, obj):
        return not obj.is_blocked # invert the boolean value
    is_blocked_col.boolean = True
    is_blocked_col.admin_order_field = 'is_blocked'
    is_blocked_col.short_description  = 'Is Blocked'

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

If you use this method it will still show the on/off icon. If `is_blocked=True` then `return not obj.is_blocked` is going to return `False` which shown as red icon as desired by you.

**EDIT**

If you want to use the words `True/False` instead of the red/green icons you can set

`is_blocked_col.boolean = False`

in the above code.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. The idea is that in those cases where yes/no icon is no good, True/False string is not much better. So custom method is unavoidable. Add `admin_order_field` so that would still be sortable and I shall accept your answer.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins I have updated my answer. I have tested it also and every thing works as required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I examined the corresponding django code and unfortunately this behaviour is hard-coded so the only solution is the one mentioned in the question:

```
is_blocked = BooleanField(default=False)

def is_blocked_col(self):
    return self.is_blocked
is_blocked_col.short_description = \
is_blocked_col.admin_order_field = 'is_blocked'
```

Which is much less readable than something like

```
is_blocked = BooleanField(default=False)
is_blocked.boolean = False
```

(which doesn't work)

or than forcing admin widget to `force_unicode` or something (which I am not sure how to implement)

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it by javascript and css to design you template.

you can see these link : 
    [On/Off Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957466/how-to-create-an-on-off-switch-with-javascript-css) ,
    [IOS Buttons](http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com/) , 
    [Switch Buttons](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/) ,
    [CSS3 Buttns](http://jsfiddle.net/)

I think it is too easy to use any of them

GOOD LUCK
REGARDS

Mohammad

Comment: I don't need extra functionality, just the opposite I want to disable on/off icon, leaving simply `True`/`False` message.

Comment: when you have extra functionality .. you can choose one of them

Comment: I can even display a dog barking loudly for 'yes' and a cat mewing for 'no'. But that's not what I need. I need `True`/`False` behaviour which I hoped would not be a great deal.