# Can we put text on the "On/Off" switch that is similar when using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

iOS7 has a very good style of switch that looks like:

[image: switch]

I think this is an effective and efficient design. HTML5 switch seems to only allow us placing text like this:

[image: HTML5]

I did find some alternative solution here: http://colintoh.com/css3-flip-switch

Well, the alternative solution isn't "switch" but rather styled div animations. They work slightly different than a "switch," and more importantly I like how the switch moves left and right and keep the text on top (very good indicator/navigator for switching between two pages).

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: HTML5 does not have any kind of 'native' switch if thats what your asking, solutions will always be css styled divs/spans etc, with CSS for styling and potentially animations and/or javascript to add effects/behaviour,.  This of course gives you the full power to create any kinds of switch design you want, so I would a least attempt something, another example http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-toggle-switch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called "Toggle Switch," you can download it here: http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/

After you download it you can put this in your HTML:

```
<label>View</label>
<div class="switch-toggle switch-candy">
    <input id="textA" name="view" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="textA" onclick="">textA</label>

    <input id="textB" name="view" type="radio">
    <label for="textB" onclick="">textB</label>

    <a>Switch Link Here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 does not have any kind of 'native' switch if thats what your asking, solutions will always be css styled divs/spans etc, with CSS for styling and potentially animations and/or javascript to add effects/behaviour,.  This of course gives you the full power to create any kinds of switch design you want, so I would a least attempt something, another example [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-toggle-switch/), but you probably want [this](http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com/) or [this](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/) which I notice has you first switch design, just choose the iOS one/s

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957466/how-to-create-an-on-off-switch-with-javascript-css)